# Proof of a theorem about isometries of $\mathbb{R^n}$

Tags: isometry

**I am looking for a thorough proof of the following theorem**

*Theorem:* If an isometry of $\mathbb{R^n}$ fixes a non-empty set of points F, then it fixes the smallest affine subspace of $\mathbb{R^n}$ which contain F.

Comment: Use the fact that this space is just the space of (barycentric) combinations $x_1X_1+...+x_nX_n$ with $X_i\in F$ and $\sum _1^n x_1=1$. If $g$ fixes the $X_i$, it fixes their barycenter.

Comment: And, of course, use the fact that any isometry of $\Bbb R^n$ is of the form $f(x)=Ax+b$ for an orthogonal matrix $A$ (in particular, is an affine linear map).